# Nvidia NPP static link on windows

Tags: nvidia, npp

Is there no static linking option for windows for nvidia's performance primitives libraries?

The guide for npp recommends static linking, and shows how for linux, but not windows.
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html

Comment: Only dynamic linking is possible on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to statically link NPP on windows.